# Guidance needed to choose the right IDE

Tags: jakarta-ee, ide

I am into developing an e-commerce application with Spring and Hibernate. I am quite confused over choosing the IDE ( Netbeans or Eclipse). Netbeans is found to be comparatively easy for plugin installation and adding servers whereas Eclipse is more light-weight.

Could you tell me which one is better? By the way I'm gonna use Apache Tomcat server.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both are a good IDE.  I have been on a project that switched from Netbeans to Eclipse without much effort, we were doing early Scala.  This is really a matter of a personal choice, I like Eclipse better. I find integration with different packages, installs etc to be easy.  Eclipse also comes with GlassFish J2EE.  You can create J2EE project and run from Eclipse without having to configure everything, it is done for you out of the box.  Creating a new J2EE project in NetBeans and running it might be just as easy, I don't know.

Again this is just from my experience, you should play with both and see what works better for you.

Answer (score 0):

My +1 for eclipse.
Eclipse has a huge set of plugins and also is as easy for setting up servers any other frameworks.

having said that I have used both NetBeans and Eclipse in projects and both were easy to use, and are great IDEs. What you need to do is, just use any IDE and get used to it. it will not be a big deal for you to switch between IDEs once you have the basics right.

I personally use Eclipse at home for my projects, IBM RAD at work and netbeans in 2 old projects at work. All have been excellent. I would suggest instead of pondering over an IDE try to understand the project that you are doing.